# Why is ansible synchronize module synchronizing my playbook_dir even if i do not specify

Tags: directory, ansible, synchronization, file-transfer

I wish to copy files and folders from `{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/<file or folder>` on localhost to a remote host destination but it also copies over all the contents under `{{ playbook_dir }}` directory.

The below playbook has `host` mentioned as `remote host`

Below is my ansible playbook which works fine when the `src` is a file or set of files.

```
   - name: "Copying files from local ansible host tmpfiles to target Destination server `{{ inventory_hostname }}`when the destination path is specified"
     synchronize:
        src: "{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/{{ item | basename }}"
        dest: "/tmp/moht/"
        mode: push
        rsync_opts: ""
     with_items:
       - "{{ source_file.split() }}"
```

The problem occurs when there is a folder inside `{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/`.

The problem is with any directory say `shif` i.e `{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/shif` other files from `playbook_dir` directory also get copied over to destination folder `/tmp/mohtas`
Here is how ansible WRONGLY constructed the rsync command as seen in the debug.

```
TASK [Copying files from local ansible host tmpfiles to target Destination server `desthost`when the destination path is specified] ***
task path: /web/playbooks/filecopy/copyfiles.yml:215
changed: [desthost] => (item=/tmp/shif) => {"changed": true, "cmd": "/bin/rsync --delay-updates -F --compress --archive --rsh=/usr/share/centrifydc/bin/ssh -S none -o StrictHostKeyChecking=no -o UserKnownHostsFile=/dev/null  --out-format=<<CHANGED>>%i %n%L /web/playbooks/filecopy/tmpfiles/93/shif destuser@desthost:/tmp/mohtas/", "item": "/tmp/shif", "msg": ".d..t...... ./\n<f+++++++++ adddesttohost.yml\n<f+++++++++ allmwhosts.hosts\n<f+++++++++ backupfiles.yml\n<f+++++++++ copyfiles.retry\n<f+++++++++ copyfiles.yml\n<f+++++++++ dircheck.yml\n<f+++++++++ dircheckinner.yml\ncd+++++++++ shif/\n<f+++++++++ shif/72.log\ncd+++++++++ shif/log/\n<f+++++++++ shif/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ shif/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ shif/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ shif/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ shif/log/13/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/copyfilesvelocity.yml\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/reqvelocityinstall.yml\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/velocityserver.hosts\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/13/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/14/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/14/allmwhosts.hosts\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/16/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/16/allmwhosts.hosts\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/19/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/19/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/22/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/23/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/24/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/24/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/25/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/25/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/26/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/26/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/27/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/27/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/28/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/28/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/29/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/29/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/30/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/30/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/31/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/31/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/32/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/32/ssl.conf\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/35/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/36/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/37/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/37/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/38/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/39/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/40/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/41/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/42/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/42/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/43/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/43/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/44/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/44/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/45/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/45/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/46/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/46/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/47/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/47/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/48/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/48/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/49/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/49/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/50/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/50/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/51/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/51/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/52/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/52/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/53/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/53/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/54/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/54/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/55/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/55/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/56/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/56/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/58/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/58/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/61/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/61/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/62/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/62/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/63/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/63/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/64/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/64/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/66/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/66/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/66/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/67/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/67/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/67/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/68/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/68/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/68/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/69/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/69/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/69/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/70/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/70/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/70/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/71/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/71/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/71/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/73/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/73/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/73/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/74/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/74/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/74/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/75/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/75/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/75/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/76/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/76/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/76/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/77/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/77/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/77/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/78/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/78/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/78/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/79/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/79/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/79/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/80/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/80/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/80/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/81/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/81/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/81/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/82/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/82/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/82/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/83/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/83/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/83/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/72.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/13/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/72.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/13/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/72.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/13/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/87/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/87/sixhundredperm.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/88/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/88/sixhundredperm.txt\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/88/test.txt\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/72.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/13/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/72.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/13/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/72.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/13/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/72.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/13/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/72.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/1.log\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/2.log\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/12/\ncd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/13/\n<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/13/2.log\n", "rc": 0, "stdout_lines": [".d..t...... ./", "<f+++++++++ adddesttohost.yml", "<f+++++++++ allmwhosts.hosts", "<f+++++++++ backupfiles.yml", "<f+++++++++ copyfiles.retry", "<f+++++++++ copyfiles.yml", "<f+++++++++ dircheck.yml", "<f+++++++++ dircheckinner.yml", "cd+++++++++ shif/", "<f+++++++++ shif/72.log", "cd+++++++++ shif/log/", "<f+++++++++ shif/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ shif/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ shif/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ shif/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ shif/log/13/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/copyfilesvelocity.yml", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/reqvelocityinstall.yml", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/velocityserver.hosts", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/13/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/14/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/14/allmwhosts.hosts", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/16/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/16/allmwhosts.hosts", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/19/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/19/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/22/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/23/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/24/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/24/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/25/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/25/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/26/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/26/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/27/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/27/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/28/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/28/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/29/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/29/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/30/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/30/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/31/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/31/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/32/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/32/ssl.conf", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/35/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/36/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/37/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/37/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/38/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/39/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/40/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/41/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/42/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/42/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/43/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/43/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/44/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/44/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/45/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/45/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/46/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/46/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/47/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/47/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/48/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/48/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/49/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/49/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/50/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/50/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/51/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/51/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/52/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/52/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/53/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/53/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/54/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/54/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/55/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/55/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/56/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/56/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/58/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/58/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/61/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/61/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/62/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/62/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/63/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/63/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/64/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/64/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/66/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/66/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/66/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/67/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/67/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/67/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/68/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/68/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/68/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/69/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/69/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/69/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/70/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/70/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/70/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/71/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/71/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/71/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/73/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/73/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/73/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/74/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/74/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/74/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/75/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/75/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/75/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/76/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/76/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/76/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/77/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/77/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/77/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/78/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/78/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/78/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/79/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/79/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/79/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/80/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/80/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/80/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/81/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/81/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/81/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/82/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/82/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/82/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/83/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/83/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/83/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/72.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/84/shif/log/13/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/72.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/85/log/13/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/72.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/86/shif/log/13/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/87/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/87/sixhundredperm.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/88/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/88/sixhundredperm.txt", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/88/test.txt", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/72.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/89/shif/log/13/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/72.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/90/shif/log/13/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/72.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/91/shif/log/13/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/72.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/92/shif/log/13/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/72.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/1.log", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/2.log", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/12/", "cd+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/13/", "<f+++++++++ tmpfiles/93/shif/log/13/2.log"]}
```

How can I make sure whether a file or folder is present under `{{ playbook_dir }}/tmpfiles/{{ Latest_Build_Number }}/` only that file / folder or a combination of files and folders get copied over to the destination folder `/tmp/mohtas` ?

Answer (score 0):

The issue of extra files getting copied was because of the `rsync_opts: ""`

I set `default(omit)` if `rsync_opts` was blank at runtime.

Learning: never keep `rsync_opts: ""` better omit.